# calc and evaluation of rational fractions

Tags: calc

I am new to using calc. Is it possible that the evaluation of ((x-1)/(x+1))+((x+1)/(x-1))=> returns ((x-1)/(x+1))+((x+1)/(x-1))=>(2 x^2 + 2) / (x^2 - 1)

Comment: Looking at the [Simplifying Formulas](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Simplifying-Formulas) chapter of the Calc manual, I didn't find anything that would do that.

Comment: I think it should be possible since nrat can produce the output.

Comment: Indeed - I didn't find `nrat` because I didn't look at the [right place](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#Polynomials) - of course, after @Tobias pointed it out, my hindsight increased to 20/20 :-).

Answer (score 3):

Original question:

> Is it possible that the evaluation of ((x-1)/(x+1))+((x+1)/(x-1))=> returns ((x-1)/(x+1))+((x+1)/(x-1))=>(2 x^2 + 2) / (x^2 - 1)

The [calc function `nrat`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Polynomials.html#index-nrat-1728) transforms its expression argument to a rational expression.

You can try `nrat(((x-1)/(x+1))+((x+1)/(x-1)))` with
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(calc-eval "nrat(((x-1)/(x+1))+((x+1)/(x-1)))")`

The result is:

```
(2*x^2 + 2) / (x^2 - 1)
```

If you prefer to work with the Calc stack you can put `((x-1)/(x+1))+((x+1)/(x-1))` on the stack with the help of algebraic input <kbd>'</kbd>.
Afterwards type <kbd>a</kbd> for *Algebraic simplifications* and <kbd>n</kbd> for *Normalize rational expression*.

Comment: Nice! I missed that.

Comment: I know that, but that doesnt answer my question. I want to have an output like 2:3+3:4=>  :  \evalto \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{4} \to \frac{17}{12}
 in LaTeX mode.

Comment: But that is *NOT* what you asked.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not speak English fluently. The workaround I found is to evaluate (for example) $ ((x - 1) / (x + 1)) + ((x + 1) / (x - 1)) = nrat (((x - 1) / (x + 1)) + ((x + 1) / (x - 1))) $ which returns $ frac {x - 1} {x + 1} + \ frac {x + 1} {x - 1} = \ frac {2 x ^ 2 + 2} {x ^ 2 - 1} $ in a LaTeX document with embedded calc. I think it can exist better solution.